# Python "import random" generate "ImportError: cannot import name 'MethodType'"

Tags: python, visual-studio

I am using

- Visual Studio 2017
- Python 3.6 64 bit

When I use the Visual Studio built interactive environment, I am about to "import random" no problems

When I run the code (without the debugger) I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Andy Slater\github\Introduction to Python Fundamentals\Introduction to Python Fundamentals\sorting.py", line 149, in <module>
    import random
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\random.py", line 41, in <module>
    from types import MethodType as _MethodType, BuiltinMethodType as _BuiltinMethodType
ImportError: cannot import name 'MethodType'
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no pro, but I think you're having a dependency problem. Have you messed around in the python directory at all? Random comes with the standard library, and so does types. You can try un-installing and re-installing python, or updating it. You might also try to see if you can just pip install 'types'